# PHP $_POST Notice: Undefined index: regno on line 33

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this error. I thought it's on misplaced of `'` the `$_POST`, but if I do that (eg `$_POST['regno']`) it will give `T_ESCAPED` error.
How I can fix this?
Here is the code of line 33:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE RegNo='$_POST[regno]' AND
password='$_POST[password]' AND Status='Enabled'";
```

I'm using Wamp as my localhost.
Thanks!

Comment: This code is highly vulnerable to SQL injections!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the post value like this

```
 $reg_no = isset($_POST['regno']) ? $_POST['regno'] : '';
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE RegNo='".$reg_no."' AND password='".$_POST['password']."' AND Status='Enabled'";
```

Comment: Hey, the error did disappear. Thanks @arun-krish ! ><

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that your variables exists before trying to save them :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['regno']) && !empty($_POST['regno'])){
    $regno =$_POST['regno'];
}

if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password =$_POST['password'];
}

if(isset($password) && isset($regno)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE RegNo='$regno' AND password='$password' AND Status='Enabled'";
}
?>
```

Also keep in mind that using POST var like this is very exposed to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE RegNo='".$_POST['regno']."' AND password='".$_POST['password']."' AND Status='Enabled'";
```

Comment: The error still appear @akhil-thayyil

Comment: print_r($_POST) and check whether you have the params regno and password set in POST